# Remove autogenerated Javadoc comment eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is there any way to remove the annoying "@Javadoc" comments that eclipse generates with every new class? 
I tried to remove it in the preferences but i dont get it

Comment: Do you know Eclipse JDT? If so, you can parse the java file and then pick up code without comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the Settings of your Eclipse.
`Window->Preferences` than go to `Java->Code Style -> Code Templates` and change the Comments at `Files`. You can also change every style for Method and so on.

regards

Comment: For example, it would be most useful on any complex project to change the *Catch block body* to use your project's favorite log system instead of `${exception_var}.printStackTrace();`.